# NextJS AppEngine App Connection issue to CloudSQL Postgres when using Prisma

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, prisma, next-auth

I am trying to use [Next-Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) in my NextJS React application. I am using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) for my ORM to talk to my CloudSQL PostgreSQL instance. I first tried Next-Auth without any Database and it was working fine both locally and on my GCP deployments.

My application is deployed to GCP using AppEngine. I followed Prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql). Everything works fine locally when I use `cloud-sql-proxy` with this DATABASE_URL:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/db-name
```

The CloudSQL DB and AppeEngine app are under the same project. I have both Private and Public IP enabled for CloudSQL. Also, both of these settings are set already.

```
Google Cloud services authorization: Enabled
App Engine authorization: Enabled
```

According to GCP doc, All apps in the same project are authorized by default to talk to CloudSQ. I also use this DATABASE_URL:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<w.x.y.z>:5432/db-name
```

Where `<w.x.y.z>` is my cloudsql public IP. I keep getting this error:

```
Can't reach database server at `<w.x.y.z>`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `<w.x.y.z>`:`5432`. PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation
```

Also, it is worth-noting that I already have followed the [GCP instruction](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#node.js). And my App Engine default service account has Cloud SQL Client role.

Any thought what else might be missing?

Tried to connect app engine to cloud sql using Prisma in next-auth for my typescript NextJS application.

Comment: Are you using App Engine standard or flex?

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine runs the Cloud SQL Proxy for you, but uses a Unix Socket. So instead of the URL you're using, you'll want something like:

```
postgresql://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@localhost/dbname?host=/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:myinstance
```

See [the docs for details](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard).

Comment: Can you elaborate it more, I am using Prisma ORM to post the user data into my GCP PostgreSQL database.

This is my .env `Database URL = "postgresql://<USER>:PASSWORD>@<w.x.y.z>:5432/<database>?host=/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:myinstance`


But I'm still getting the error
`PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid prisma.user.findUnique() invocation:

Authentication failed against database server at <HOST>, the provided database credentials for postgres are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at <HOST>`

Comment: That error means your app is reaching your database server but failing authentication. Check your user name and password. Otherwise, your URL looks good. I'd switch to using "localhost" just to make it clear that you're not actually hitting that IP address directly.

Comment: my username and password is correct, I am able to signing to dbeaver with same credentials. I am able to update the schema but not able to post the data using prisma

Comment: And If i input localhost, How will it get the IP address of my database

Comment: The Cloud SQL Proxy run by App Engine does it for you. You connect to the Unix socket and don't worry about the rest.